# Произошло шифрование строки. Помогите произвести дешифрование

Tags: python-3.x, криптография, reverse

Здраствуйте, я новичок в Python. Произошло шифрование строки `encrypt("XXXXXXXX")`. Помогите пожалуйста произвести дешифрование.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def encrypt(text):
    for letter in text:
        num = ord(letter)
        print((num * 71) % 0x100, end=' ')
    print("")

encrypt("XXXXXXXX")  # first part
# Output:
# 177 244 80 190 151 201 147 179


import random

def encrypt(text):
    for letter in text:
        padding = random.randint(0, 0xffffffff)
        num = ord(letter) + padding * 0x100
        print((num * 71) % 0x10000000000, end=' ')
    print("")

encrypt("XXXXXXXXXXX")  # second part
# Output:
# 525947173269 385674887347 826626104207 1038741816624 1942636332 500176323152 308306622286 219678138270 409399376492 188475543447 321720464514
```

[image: посмотреть скриншот]

Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Для первого случая нам известен остаток от деления на 256 кода каждого символа, умноженного на 71.
Остается решить уравнение

> код символа * 71 ≡ зашифрованный код (mod 256)

(Код символа умноженный на 71 сравним с зашифрованным кодом по модулю 256)

> код символа * 71 * 71<sup>-1</sup> ≡ зашифрованный код * 71<sup>-1</sup> (mod 256)
> код символа ≡ зашифрованный код * 71<sup>-1</sup> (mod 256)

Обратное по модулю можно найти, например, с помощью расширенного алгоритма евклида. Для 71 по модулю 256 это будет [119](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=71%5E-1+%28mod+256%29)

Если изначальный символ входил в таблицу ASCII, т.е. его код не превышал 255, то ответ получится однозначный, иначе придется подбирать. Будем считать, что входил (скорее всего, так и есть), значит ответом будет остаток от деления на 256 зашифрованного кода, умноженного на 119.

Например, кодом первого символа будет 71 (символ `G`)

Второй случай может показаться страшным, но прибавленное число ни на что не влияет, потому, что

> x + y * 256 ≡ x (mod 256)

Кодом первого символа во втором случае будет 67 (символ `C`)